# Single point estimate of joint posterior distribution

Tags: r, bayesian, regression-coefficients, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

This is a very basic Bayesian beginner question about what to do when one does not want a full parameter distribution but only a single set of parameters. Example: Let's say we have a number of points and we want to draw a regression line. MCMC provides a large number of plausible combinations of intercepts and slopes but only one pair of intercept and slope can be used to draw one regression line.

Worked `R` example. First, generate example data:

```
set.seed(1404)
x <- runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 150)
y <- jitter(.3*x^2 + 3*x + 15 + 500*log(x), 1000)
ex <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

[image]

Bayesian linear regression can be done multiple ways (this is not a software question), let's keep it simple using `rstanarm`:

```
library(rstanarm)
mod1 <- stan_glm(y ~ x, data=ex)
summary(mod1)
```

That will sample a huge number of more or less plausible combinations of coefficients and print descriptive statistics of those:

```
Estimates:
              mean   sd    10%   50%   90%
(Intercept) 155.1   94.8  34.9 153.9 277.0
x            58.6    1.0  57.2  58.6  59.9
sigma       442.5   32.0 403.0 440.1 484.1
```

These are however mean and quantiles of each parameter of its own. If I wanted to draw one single regression line in the above plot then I needed exactly one Intercept and one x-coefficient. In the simple linear case I could probably just take the mean of the Intercepts and the x-coefficients in the posterior distribution. In more complicated situations: Do we know that the mean of the coefficients makes sense in the joint distribution?

If we did a more complicated regression, knowing the data generation process, maybe

```
mod2 <- stan_glm(y ~ I(x^2) + x + I(log(x)), data=ex)
```

is it still sensible, to use each coefficient's single-point estimate and assume those single-point estimates combine to a sensible joint estimate?

In my example, the posterior means form a decent regression line but my question is, whether we can always assume that or what would be a good way to find a joint single point estimate of the coefficients. 
[image]

Comment: I suppose the general answer must be "no", because if you imagine a bi-modal posterior distribution, then the mean of the distribution may not be a good model. So, I suppose what you really want is the posterior mode. With MCMC this is difficult. I guess you need to use Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) estimation.

Comment: @TimMak "bi-modal posterior" was something I had blurredly in mind but did not find the words. I do not really mind whether we talk about a mode, a median or whatever. There should be a way to extract a "good" parameter set that represents the overall result for when a distribution is not suitable for the use of data after the regression. There should be something like "highest density in the parameter space" coordinates or a "joint likelihood" for parameter combinations or something, preferably readily accessible in software.

Comment: Like I said you can't do it easily with MCMC. If you must use MCMC, then one solution would be to fit a joint density over the posterior and search for the maximum. Alternatively, you may want to invoke the Central Limit Theorem and argue that with a large enough sample, the posterior is approximately normal and hence the mean makes sense.

Comment: Is there a beginner friendly way into "finding the maximum of the joint density over the posterior"? That would sound like a great answer.